# Android ListView selecting item replaces text in top list view item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, xamarin.android

I have a ListFragment that shows items from a database.  When the user clicks on an item in the list view, details appear in a second fragment.  However, the ListView also replaces the text in the top item with the text of the selected item.  I can still click on the top item and get details of what should be there, and it will correct the text.  I'm at a loss for what could be causing this, as the ItemClick code doesn't change anything in the ListView, it only reads data from the Event Args.  Does anyone know what could be causing this?

```
    CardFragment cardFragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<CardFragment>(Resource.Id.frgCard);
    if (cardFragment == null)
    {
        cardFragment = CardFragment.NewCardFragment(e.Id);
        var transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.frgCard, cardFragment);
        transaction.SetTransition(FragmentTransit.FragmentFade);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    else
    {
        cardFragment.ChangeCard(e.Id);
    }
```

Here is the List adapter (a SimpleCursorAdapter):

```
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Activity, Resource.Layout.card_list_item, mCursor, columns, to);
                cursorAdapter.StringConversionColumn = 0; // Sort Name Column
                cursorAdapter.FilterQueryProvider = new FilterQueryProvider(Activity);
```

Comment: post your list adapter

Comment: i bet it's a matter of view recycling

Comment: I added the list adapter code.